# Get all the palindromes in a string

Tags: php

I was asked to write a program in php where all the occurrences of palindromes in a given string need to be printed.

Example: For the string  I O M K I L O L I K T C J I O P L L P O

The answer would be:

O P L L P O   and 
 K I L O L I K

While doing this it should kept in mind that every palindrome that is more than 3 characters in length can be broken down into more palindromes but you just need to print out the longest size possible for each set (so, for the example string, you SHOULD NOT  print  LOL,  LL , PLLP and ILOLI)

I tried it but could only manage to do this:

```
$data = 'I O M K I L O L I K T C J I O P L L P O';
$data = str_replace(' ', '', $data);    

$palindromes = [];
for($i=0; $i<strlen($data); $i++ )  {
    for($j=3; $j<=(strlen($data)-$i); $j++){
        $word = substr($data, $i, $j);
        $reverse_word = strrev($word);
        if($word == $reverse_word){
            print "Word: ".$word."<br/>";                   
        }
    }    
}
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
Word: KILOLIK
Word: ILOLI
Word: LOL
Word: OPLLPO
Word: PLLP
```

Which is not the expected ouput. What should I to get rid of the strings like ILOLI, LOL PLLP because I am expected to get the longest palindrome.

Comment: Something tells me strpos() could help but I am not sure where and how to place it ?

Answer (score 0):

According your example, you mention the answer would be O P L L P O (six characters long) and K I L O L I K (seven characters long), but later you imply only the *longest* palindrome should be returned?

Assuming you mean the later case, you can first assign all the palindromes to array and then sort the array, like this:

```
function str_length_sort($first, $second) {
  return strlen($second) - strlen($first);
}
$data = 'I O M K I L O L I K T C J I O P L L P O';
$data = str_replace(' ', '', $data);    
$palindromes = [];
for($i=0; $i<strlen($data); $i++ )  {
  for($j=3; $j<=(strlen($data)-$i); $j++){
    $word = substr($data, $i, $j);
    $reverse_word = strrev($word);
     if($word == $reverse_word){
        $palindromes[] = $word;                           
      }
  }    
}
usort($palindromes, 'str_length_sort');
$max = strlen($palindromes[0]);
foreach ($palindromes as $p) {
  $length = strlen($p);
  if ($length >= $max) {
    echo $p;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This gives me the same result that I got when I get a print_r of the array palindromes.

Comment: The question aims at getting all the longest possible palindromes and the entered string could have N characters.

Comment: So, you mean there might be many of palindromes that are, let's say, seven characters long and the script should print them all? I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that is what is expected.

Comment: Well, try my current code with any data :-) Worked for me, when I tried with different strings as $data.

Comment: Yes, of course with that implementation because OPLLPO is shorter word than KILOLIK :-) Should the code return the ones that are **longest** or **longest AND second longest** or how you define the _longest_?

Comment: The problem clearly states the expected answer is  OPLLPO and KILOLIK. The second part (which starts with "while doing this...") answers your query relevant to defining longest.